# Can I call .post value into a hidden input in this situation?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, .post

Is that possible I call the .post data to a hidden input, and then get the hidden input value. The reason I am doing this because bp_core_get_user_domain() is not working in URL(search.php), I am using wordpress.

```js
$('#tag').click(function(){
$.post("search.php", {
   search_id: $("#id_tag").text()
   },
   function(data)
   {
    $("#member_id").val(data);
   }
  );//$.post
  
  });
```

```html
//this is not search.php

<?php
<input type="hidden" id="member_id" />
$member_id=(hidden input value);
$user_link=bp_core_get_user_domain( $member_id );
<input type="text" id="tag"/>
?>
```

Comment: Usually, you just use PHP to echo a `json_encode()`ed Associative  Array, which will become an Object in your success function's `data` argument. Use JavaScript to create HTML in your success function.  Not sure why you want to use a hidden input. You can send data in your `$.post()` function's second argument.

Comment: Thanks for repsonse. How to create html in the success function?can you provide an example?

Comment: `function(data)
   {
    $("#member_id").val(data);
   }` is your success function. The argument before that parses an Object to be retrieved on `search.php`, like `$_POST['search_id']`. `search.php` is where you need to `echo json_encode($assocArray);` which comes back as the highlighted function's `data` argument as JSON. You should be able to get the properties as they were in your PHP `$assocArray`, like `data.someProperty` inside your success function.

Comment: what is 'bp_core_get_user_domain()', is that function? That cause me a problem, whenever I put this into my search.php, it cause problem, in normal php file, it is OK.

Comment: It returns exactly what the function says: http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/buddypress/nav.html?_functions/index.html . You can pass a member_id property in you `$.post()` function's second Object argument, then deal with it on `search.php` as `bp_core_get_user_domain($_POST['member_id'])`.

Comment: If I put bp_core_get_user_domain() in my search.php, it doesn't work and cause problem. That's why I am trying to take back member_id and put it into a hidden input and tried to called the value, why I have to do this, because I will fetch some data from mysql in search.php, and I need  bp_core_get_user_domain(), since  bp_core_get_user_domain() doesn't work in search.php, so I have to figure it out a solution way.

Comment: You would have to `include` the wordpress file where `function bp_core_get_user_domain(){}` is created or inherited.

Answer (score 0):

Use WordPress Ajax and store the value with `update_option('member_id');` and than do a query to check if what that value is.